# закрываются обе формы при закрытии одной

Tags: c#, .net

при попытке открыть form2 и закрыть form1 закрываются обе
код открытия form2 и закрытия form1:

```
form1.Close();                 
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```

код инициализация приложения:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Помогите решить проблему

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59006931/4928642

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут всё очень просто. `Form1` у вас - это главная форма в приложении. По-этому при её закрытии заканчивается жизненный цикл WinForms.

Если вы хотите чтобы форму не было видно во время открытия другой формы, вы можете просто её спрятать, а потом показать:

```
form1.Hide();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
form1.Show();
```